# CSS and JS assets not loaded at all in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

After deploying my site to a fresh Laravel Forge server the JS and CSS files are not being loaded, they are not even being shown in the actually rendered HTML.

I've tried a few things already like running `php artisan basset:check`, which gives me three green DONEs. I've even tried running `php artisan backpack:install`. Locally everything works fine. Any help is much appreciated.

**PHP VERSION:**
PHP 8.3.3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 15 2024 18:38:52) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.3.3-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

**LARAVEL VERSION:**

- 10.43.0.0

**BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:**

- backpack/basset: 1.2.2
- backpack/crud: 6.6.1
- backpack/generators: v4.0.3
- backpack/permissionmanager: 7.1.1
- backpack/pro: 2.1.2
- backpack/settings: 3.1.0
- backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using a different hostname. Where I previously used api-env.domain.com, I changed this to api.env.domain.com and updated the `APP_URL` accordingly. I'm not sure if the dash in the hostname is not supported, but this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `APP_URL` in your .env file is correctly pointing to the URL you use to access your application in the browser.
For example: https://yourdomain.com

More info available [here.](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/basset?tab=readme-ov-file#faq)

Comment: Thank you for your help! The `APP_URL` is set up correctly already so I'm afraid that's not it. I have done some debugging and when I `dd()` the `$href` of the `echoCss` method in BassetManager.php (line 115) I do see the correct path to one of the css files (in this case, storage/basset/unpkg.com/@digitallyhappy/backstrap@0.5.1/dist/css/legacy.css?f8ca1ce56690). However, if I just `dump()` instead of `dd()`, I don't see anything.

Comment: I also checked the disk configuration and storage link, both are ok. I actually see the files on disk as well.

Comment: I am running out of ideas, even `BASSET_DEV_MODE=true` does not do anything.